# Building a list of expressions via Expression Trees

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I have the following method which builds an expression based on a column name and value:

```
public Func<TSource, bool> SimpleComparison<TSource>(string property, object value)
{
    var type = typeof (TSource);
    var pe = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyReference = Expression.Property(pe, property);
    var constantReference = Expression.Constant(value);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>
        (Expression.Equal(propertyReference, constantReference),
        new[] { pe }).Compile();
}
```

I am trying to create a list of expressions, then query my datasource with the final concatenated/compiled expression.

I have tried to use `Expression.Block` but the concept is a bit difficult for me to grasp.  I have also seen `Expression.Loop` but am not sure if it's what I need to use here.

Ideally, I would be able to do something like this:

```
var filters = request.Filter.Filters;

IQueryable<MyDTO> myDataSource = context.MyDataSource;

var expressions = null;

foreach (var filter in filters)
{

    expressions.Add(SimpleExpression<MyDTO>(filter.Name, filter.Value));

}

return myDataSource.Where(expressions);
```

Any ideas on how to do something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're over-thinking things. You don't need to combine your expressions at all. The only complicated part is implementing `SimpleComparison`, but you've done that already. Well, mostly. You should be returning `Expression<Func<...>>`, not `Func<...>`, so it should be

```
public Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> SimpleComparison<TSource>(string property, object value)
{
    // ...
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>
        (Expression.Equal(propertyReference, constantReference),
        new[] { pe });
}
```

Once you have that, you can chain the filters by calling `Where` repeatedly, like so:

```
var filters = request.Filter.Filters;
IQueryable<MyDTO> query = context.MyDataSource;
foreach (var filter in filters)
    query = query.Where(SimpleComparison<MyDTO>(filter.Name, filter.Value));
return query;
```

Comment: I noticed that the `.Where()` seems to return an IEnumerable rather than IQueryable.  Wouldn't this create multiple database calls for each filter in filters?  Ideally, the datasource would only be queried once, just with a combined lists of expressions.

Comment: This solution makes the same assumption I did when I first read the question, that the filters are joined with `&&`. If they are instead joined using `||` this won't work. If they are indeed `&&` together this is a much simpler solution than mine.

Comment: @BradfordDillon If they are joined using `||`, then chain them using `.Union`: `query = query.Union(context.MyDataSource.Where(expression));`.

Comment: @BradfordDillon Yes but it looks like this solution will query the datasource multiple times (so if there are 4 items in `filters` then the code will execute 4 SQL queries).  You solution appears to only make one query, plus I like how easy your code makes it to switch from using `.AndAlso()` to use `||`.  `expressions.Aggregate((e, next) => Expression.AndAlso(e, next));` was what I was really looking for, I believe.

Comment: @user1477388 There are two `.Where()` functions. The one you would end up using, `Queryable.Where`, returns an `IQueryable<T>`, the other one, `Enumerable.Where` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`. Furthermore, most mappers (I'm assuming Entity Framework) tend to be smart enough about chaining the `Where`s together into a single query instead of multiple queries.

Comment: @Shlomo I, too, assumed that `.Where()` would use the IQueryable override; however, from my earlier test using `.Where(Func(TSource, bool))` it seemed to use IEnumerable.  I will try again now that I am using Expression and see which override it uses.

Comment: @user1477388 Right, that's why I mentioned that in my answer. `IQueryable<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so both `Enumerable` and `Queryable` extension methods are available. `Queryable.Where` takes `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`. `Enumerable.Where` takes `Func<T, bool>`. Regular overload resolution rules will resolve `queryable.Where(filter)` to either `Enumerable.Where(queryable, filter)` or `Queryable.Where(queryable, filter)` depending on whether `filter` is an expression tree or a delegate.

Answer (score 2):

I faced your exact problem recently and the below solution worked for me when trying to combine multiple expressions with either && or ||:

```
    public Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> SimpleComparison<TSource>(List<QueryFilterObject> queryFilterObjects)
{
        //initialize the body expression
        BinaryExpression bodyExpression = null;
        BinaryExpression andExpressionBody = null;
        BinaryExpression orExpressionBody = null;

        //create parameter expression
        ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "DynamicFilterQuery");

        //list of binary expressions to store either the || or && operators
        List<BinaryExpression> andExpressions = new List<BinaryExpression>();
        List<BinaryExpression> orExpressions = new List<BinaryExpression>();

        foreach (var queryFilterObject in queryFilterObjects)
        {
            //create member property expression
            var property = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, queryFilterObject.PropertyName);

            //create the constant expression value
            var constantExpressionValue = Expression.Constant(queryFilterObject.Value, queryFilterObject.PropertyType);

            //create the binary expression clause based on the comparison operator
            BinaryExpression clause = null;
            if (queryFilterObject.ComparisonOperator == "==")
            {
                clause = Expression.Equal(property, constantExpressionValue);
            }
            else if (queryFilterObject.ComparisonOperator == "!=")
            {
                clause = Expression.NotEqual(property, constantExpressionValue);
            }
            else if (queryFilterObject.ComparisonOperator == ">")
            {
                clause = Expression.GreaterThan(property, constantExpressionValue);
            }
            else if (queryFilterObject.ComparisonOperator == ">=")
            {
                clause = Expression.GreaterThan(property, constantExpressionValue);
            }
            else if (queryFilterObject.ComparisonOperator == "<")
            {
                clause = Expression.LessThan(property, constantExpressionValue);
            }
            else if (queryFilterObject.ComparisonOperator == "<=")
            {
                clause = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(property, constantExpressionValue);
            }

            //you should validate against a null clause....

            //assign the item either to the relevant logical comparison expression list
            if (queryFilterObject.LogicalOperator == "and" || queryFilterObject.LogicalOperator == "&&")
            {
                andExpressions.Add(clause);

            }
            else if (queryFilterObject.LogicalOperator == "or" || queryFilterObject.LogicalOperator == "||")
            {
                orExpressions.Add(clause);

            }

        }

        if (andExpressions.Count > 0)
            andExpressionBody = andExpressions.Aggregate((e, next) => Expression.And(e, next));

        if (orExpressions.Count > 0)
            orExpressionBody = orExpressions.Aggregate((e, next) => Expression.Or(e, next));

        if (andExpressionBody != null && orExpressionBody != null)
            bodyExpression = Expression.OrElse(andExpressionBody, orExpressionBody);

        if (andExpressionBody != null && orExpressionBody == null)
            bodyExpression = andExpressionBody;

        if (andExpressionBody == null && orExpressionBody != null)
            bodyExpression = orExpressionBody;

        if (bodyExpression == null)
            throw new Exception("Null Expression.");

        var finalExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<WorkOrder, bool>>(bodyExpression, parameterExpression);

        return finalExpression;

}

public class QueryFilterObject
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public Type PropertyType { get; set; }

    public object Value { get; set; }

    public string ComparisonOperator { get; set; }

    public string LogicalOperator { get; set; }


}
```

In my case I return an expression of func (`Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>`) instead of func itself (`Func<TSource, bool>`). This allows my where clause to remain as an Iqueryable otherwise returning *`Func<TSource, bool>`* instead of `*Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>*` will turn your where clause into an ienumerable.

Finally, I just call my expression like below:

```
IQueryable<MyDTO> myDataSource = context.MyDataSource;

var filter = SimpleComparison(queryFilterObjects);

if (filter != null)
            myDataSource = myDataSource.Where(filter);

//perfom other operations such as order by 

return myDataSource.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your function to instead of returning the compiled lambda have it return the base expression. Once you have those expressions stored in list, you could then use the Linq `Aggregate()` function to build your final predicate.

```
public Func<TSource, bool> CreatePredicate<TSource>(IEnumerable<Expression> expressions)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x"); 
    var body = expressions.Aggregate((e, next) => Expression.AndAlso(e, next));
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(body, parameter).Compile();

    return predicate;
}
```

This assumes you are wanting all of your statements to be joined using `&&`. If you want them joined using `||` use `Expression.OrElse` in place of `Expression.AndAlso`. If there is a mix of and filters and or filters, the solution becomes considerably more complex.

Your example above would then become

```
var filters = request.Filter.Filters;

IQueryable<MyDTO> myDataSource = context.MyDataSource;

var expressions = new List<Expression>();

foreach (var filter in filters)
{
   expressions.Add(SimpleComparison<MyDTO>(filter.Name, filter.Value));
}

var predicate = CreatePredicate<MyDTO>(expressions);

return myDataSource.Where(predicate);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer; I will study it and see how it works.